# Alphanumeric Sorting on List<object> by object field

Tags: java, sorting

I have `List<Object>`. Every `Object` have property `Number` (`String` property).I need to sort the `list` of `objects` based on `number` field Alphanumeric.

```
public class Object{
private String number;
}
```

The numbers can be (for example):

```
#3772-BOZ-007
#3772-BAZ-02
#31-002
#001
```

Every number starts with `#`
I already tried and fail with:

```
lstObjects.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement Comparable<>.compareTo method .

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Obj implements Comparable<Obj> {
    private String number;

    public Obj(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Obj o2) {
        int i1 = numPart();
        int i2 = o2.numPart();
        if (i1 == i2)
            return number.compareTo(o2.number);
        else return i2 - i1;
    }

    private int numPart() {
        int dashPos = number.indexOf('-');
        String numPart = number.substring(1, 
            dashPos == -1 ? number.length() : dashPos);
        try {
            if (numPart.length() > 0)
                return Integer.parseInt(numPart);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            //
        }
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return number;
    }
}
```

Lets Test it:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Obj> lstObjects = Arrays.asList(
                new Obj("#3772-BOZ-007"),
                new Obj("#3772-BAZ-02"),
                new Obj("#31-002"),
                new Obj("#001"),
                new Obj("#19"),
                new Obj("#22"),
                new Obj("#21"),
                new Obj("#6"));

        lstObjects.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());

        lstObjects.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
#001
#6
#19
#21
#22
#31-002
#3772-BAZ-02
#3772-BOZ-007
```

Comment: For the following input: #19, #22,#21,#6 it is not working correct. The output is: #19,#21,#22,#6 and shout be #6,#19,#21,#22

Comment: You need to play with compareTo. In this case you might want to separate numeric and alpha-numeric numbers. Edited the answer, you can check now.

Answer (score 1):

`Object` is a term already used by java.lang.Object, thus rather confusing as a sample name. I'll assume you wrote `Obj` instead for the rest of this answer.

The sort method takes a comparator that compares *the things in the list*. A comparator is an oracle that returns for any 2 objects which one is 'earlier'.

Your list consists of instances of that `Obj` class you pasted, which does not have a natural order defined.

You have two options:

### Make that class have a natural order

To do so, make the class implement `Comparable<Self>`. Thus:

```
public class Obj implements Comparable<Obj> {
    private String number;

    @Override public int compareTo(Obj other) {
        return this.number.compareTo(other.number);
    }
}

...

lstObjects.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder()):
```

### Supply a comparator that compares on the number value.

This assumes you have a `public String getNumber()` method in your `Object` class:

```
lstObjects.sort(Comparator.comparing(Obj::getNumber));
```

Comment: For the following input: #19, #22,#21,#6 it is not working correct. The output is: #19,#21,#22,#6 and shout be #6,#19,#21,#22

Comment: Because strings compare lexicographically; it is a separate issue from your main question. Extract the number, parse it to an int, compare those.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `Comparable` interface and define the sort key and mechanism of the sorting in the `compareTo()` method

example:

```java
    public class MyObject implements Comparable<MyObject> {
        private String number;

        public MyObject(String number) {
            this.number = number;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(MyObject other) {
            return this.number.compareTo(other.number);
        }
    }
```

Comment: For the following input: #19, #22,#21,#6 it is not working correct. The output is: #19,#21,#22,#6 and shout be #6,#19,#21,#22

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume, you have class

```
package stack.overflow.atest;

public class Flight {
    String number;

    public Flight(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Flight{" + "number=" + number + '}';
    }
    
}
```

This snippet invocation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Flight> list = Stream.of(
            "#3772-BOZ-007",
            "#3772-BAZ-02",
            "#31-002",
            "#001"
    ).map(Flight::new)
            .sorted((f1, f2) -> f1.number.compareTo(f2.number))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(list);
}
```

results in:

```
[Flight{number=#001}, Flight{number=#31-002}, Flight{number=#3772-BAZ-02}, Flight{number=#3772-BOZ-007}]
```

Comment: The result is wrong with the following input: #19,#22,#21,#6. The output is: [Flight{number=#19}, Flight{number=#21}, Flight{number=#22}, Flight{number=#6}]

Comment: result is correct because of alphanumeric (!) sorting

Answer (score 0):

*to sort the* `Object`s *by the leading #number*
Get the specific sort order by changing the `HashMap`-default of `groupingBy` to `TreeMap` with a passed `Comparator`.
don't confuse `Object` with `java.lang.Object`

```
static Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(?:#(\\d+))?(.*)?");
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
Stream.of(
    new Object("#3772-BOZ-007"),
    new Object("#3772-BAZ-02"),
    new Object("#31-002"),
    new Object("#001"))
.collect(groupingBy(Object::getNumber,
    () -> new TreeMap<String,List<Object>>(new Comparator<String>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(String num1, String num2) {
        Matcher m1 = pat.matcher(num1);
        Matcher m2 = pat.matcher(num2);
        m1.find();
        m2.find();
        Integer i1 = m1.group(1) != null ? Integer.parseInt(m1.group(1)) : -1;
        Integer i2 = m2.group(1) != null ? Integer.parseInt(m2.group(1)) : -1;
        String s1 = m1.groupCount() > 1 ? m1.group(2) : "";
        String s2 = m2.groupCount() > 1 ? m2.group(2) : "";
        int cmp = i1.compareTo(i2);
        return(cmp == 0 ? s1.compareTo(s2) : cmp);
      }}), toList())).values()
.forEach(l -> list.addAll(l));

System.out.println(list);
```

`Object`s sorted by their `#number`:

```
[Object{number=#001},
 Object{number=#31-002},
 Object{number=#3772-BAZ-02},
 Object{number=#3772-BOZ-007}]
```

Comment: The result is wrong with the following input: #19,#22,#21,#6. The output is: [Object{number=#19}, Object{number=#21}, Object{number=#22}, Object{number=#6}]

Comment: *(6 is greater than 1 and 2. In an alphanumeric sort the characters are lexicographically sorted from left to right.)* Even if it is quite extensive with the added `Comparator` for the special sorting, it is still the solution of choice as this is the fastest for a large amount of data.